# Rust: Reading a stream into a buffer till it is 'complete'

Tags: rust

I have a piece of code which uses the following pattern:

```
    let mut request_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    let mut buf = [0 as u8; 50]; // 50 byte read buffer
    
    while !req.parse(&request_buf).unwrap().is_complete() {
        match stream.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(size) => {
                request_buf.extend(&buf[0..size]);

            },
            Err(_) => {
                // Handle err...
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically the code is supposed to read data in from a socket into the temporary buffer `buf` and accumulates it till the fn is_complete() returns true.

I'm running into problems with the borrow checker, but I can't think of an alternative. (`cannot borrow request_buf as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable`).

Even if I try to clone request_buf to get around this, which is horribly inefficient, i get a `temporary value dropped while borrowed`no matter how widely I scope the variable for the cloned buffer.

Is this kind of pattern simply impossible to implement in Rust?  I feel I've tried everything I can think of and Rust is playing cat and mouse with me at every turn.

Comment: What exactly is the signature of `parse()`?

Comment: The signature of parse is: `pub fn parse(&mut self, buf: &'b [u8]) -> Result<usize> `.  It's from: https://docs.rs/httparse/1.4.0/httparse/

Comment: I'm new to Rust, so this may undoubtedly be a stupid question, but isn't the lifetime of the buffer at least as long as that of Request?  It's declared in the same scope...

Comment: You're right, but allowing a mutable borrow of the `Vec` would allow you to grow the `Vec` (which you indeed do), and reallocation of the `Vec` would invalidate the slices `Request` is holding onto. I've now amended the answer to (hopefully) make it clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Request` comes with a lifetime `'b` that the buffer must outlive. Thus calling `parse()` *associates* the `Request` object with the buffer, which means it's now `req` that holds a (shared) borrow of the `request_buf`. This removes the possibility of getting a mutable borrow of `request_buf` as long as `req` lives.

This is not just a whim of the borrow checker: that signature of `parse()` means that `req` intends (typically for efficiency) to *hold on* to slices pointing inside `request_buf`. A mutable borrow of `request_buf` would allow you to shrink the container or to grow it past its current capacity, causing it to reallocate. Either scenario would invalidate the slices held by `req` and cause a crash.

Comments on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3qqwc9/httparse_10_safe_zerocopy_push_http11_parser/) clarify that the parser stores no parsing state. You're expected to use a large enough buffer that partial parses are rare, and in case they happen, you just start from scratch, presumably by creating a new `Request` and giving it the whole buffer (the latter of which you were already doing). For example:

```
fn parse(mut stream: impl Read) {
    let mut request_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    let mut buf = [0 as u8; 16384]; // 16k read buffer

    let (req, headers) = loop {
        match stream.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(size) => request_buf.extend(&buf[0..size]),
            Err(_) => {} // handle err,
        }
        let mut headers = [httparse::EMPTY_HEADER; 16];
        let mut req = Request::new(&mut headers);
        if req.parse(&request_buf).unwrap().is_complete() {
            break (req, headers);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the really clear explanation.  I managed to make it work.  And I also increased the size of the buffer so that most of the HTTP requests I'm dealing with should fit without resizing.